# Is there really a safe for storing secret orders on board a B-52 bomber?

Tags: military, strategic-bomber

In the movie *[Dr. Strangelove or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove)*, a safe appears at 4:05 (you can see the sequence [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-KIAsuoMAQ&index=4&list=PLi5kiwsTn956Vd_S4ztzMOwe2AhZoag7Z)).

Is there really a safe on the B-52? If so, is it normal that bomber planes have a safe on board?

Comment: I think you could ask this on the Modern Aerial Warfare chat because the question is very much borderline on "on-topic" on this site: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36081/modern-aerial-warfare

Comment: I can only answer for the UK and some other NATO (non-US) aircraft.  There are no safes onboard the aircraft.

Comment: @Simon I think it is a curious question, but it is indeed related to aviation in that the question is about aircraft construction and military aviation operations

Comment: @Pugz Simon refered to the virst version of the question, which was edited after his comments.

Comment: @user3624251 voops, sorry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better for Skeptics.SE.

Comment: @kevin it is a question about an aircraft, I don't see why it would be OT here.

Comment: @kevin The same could be said about just about any question that starts with "is it true that...", but this particular example of the breed relates particularly to aircraft design.  Thus, I think it's in scope.  Voting to re-open.